# How to change the title for this attribute filter on my site

Tags: filter

I am not too sound with Magento files..and i am sure i accidentally change the text of this filter title. It is meant to be **"Size"** and not **"46EU"** Which file do i go to make changes

Check the image above[image]

Comment: Could you please specify what version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the admin panel for a product attribute with "**46EU**".